# searching log artifacts from old Pipeline Runs on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, logging, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, full-text-search

***tl;dr*** using Azure DevOps Pipelines, I want to search many large text log files stored as *Published artifacts*. What is the best way to do this?

For a very busy Azure DevOps Pipeline, there are many runs with many large text logs stored as *Published artifacts* (tens of Megabytes each). I want to search these old text log files for a particular error string. 
Essentially, I'd like to "grep" some files. But of course, I cannot directly logon to the Azure DevOps host and run `grep` from the command-line.

What is the best way to do a text search among many *Published artifacts* in Azure DevOps Pipelines?